# Difference between newTransformer and newTemplates in Java XSLT transformations

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

In Java, from a [`TransformerFactory`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html) for creating objects to process XSLT, and it has the methods:

- `newTransformer` which creates  `Transformer` object, which can transform XML into a result.
- `newTemplates` which creates `Templates` object which can create a `Transformer`.

The documentation for [`Transformer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html) explicitly states:

> A Transformer may be used multiple times.

My application processes various different XMLs with the same XSLT. At the start of the program I use `newTransformer` to create a `Transformer` then re-use it for  all the XMLs (making sure it's synchronized so I only use it from one thread; and calling its `reset()` method before each processing.).

That way I don't incur the cost of re-compiling the XSLT for every XML I process.

So what's the point of the `newTemplates` and the `Templates` object? Should I be using that instead, and creating a new `Transformer` object for each XML?

Comment: `xsltprocessor` is a more specific tag for such questions. Retagged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're running in a single thread, then you probably won't notice much difference.

Performance always depends on the implementation rather than on the API specification. With Saxon, when you reuse a Transformer, it retains the cache of documents loaded using the doc() function. That may be good or bad depending on whether the next transformation is going to access the same source documents. Generally my advice is to use a new Transformer for each transformation, but using the same Templates object, of course.

Answer (score 7):

The main difference is that `Templates` is thread-safe and `Transformer` is not. In addition, the documentation implies that performance optimizations may be applied during the creation of a `Templates` instance. So, the initial creation of a `Templates` instance may be more costly, but it's actual usage can offer performance gains. If you're already having to manually manage synchronization and resets, I'd say `Templates` is begging for your attention...

Comment: Right, but how I can improve calling of TransformerFactory.newTransformer() in case I haven't XSL for template?

Answer (score 4):

newTemplates() compiles the stylesheet into an internal representation that can be reused.  It's the equivalent of compiling an interpreted language (like Python) to bytecode and saving the bytecode, as opposed to reinterpreting it each time you run it.

Comment: How would you compare that with what `newTransformer` does, surely that's what it does as well?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't save the compiled stylesheet

Comment: If you reuse the `Transformer` object, then it only compiles the stylesheet once, so in that sense `newTransfomer` compile and save the compiled stylesheet, just as `newTemplates` does (or did I misunderstand something?)